# How to track when a row was created/updated automatically in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to automatically tell SQL Server that all tables should have a timestamp for insert and update?

That's probably a lot of repetitive work to do this?

Or is there another/more efficient way to do this with the transaction log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [AutoAudit](http://autoaudit.codeplex.com/)

This will add columns to a table and create DML triggers to manage those columns as well as maintain the audit trail table

I've found it to be very useful

It's certainly possible to use DDL triggers to attempt to enforce table design issues.  It's also possible to automate checking the metadata for design smells

Answer (score 6):

You can have a `RowCreated DATETIME DEFAULT (GETDATE())` to handle the date when the row was initially created automatically - but there's nothing short of writing a trigger to do the same for a `RowModified DATETIME` column.

For each table, you'd have to write an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger to handle the `RowModified` column something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trg_YourTableUpdated
ON dbo.YourTable AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.YourTable
    SET RowModified = GETDATE()
    FROM INSERTED i
    WHERE dbo.YourTable.ID = i.ID
END
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to implement this with [DML triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) in SQL Server, for the insert you could get away with `defaults` but if someone passes in a value it will overwrite the `default`