# SQL Server Delete all rows more than 10 minutes old

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I delete All rows in SQL Server that were created later than 10 minutes.
Thanks.

Comment: Let me guess: you don't have a `CREATED` column in your table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you have a column name Date_column  which is storing the timestamp. You may try like this, where mi is the abbreviation for minute:

```
DELETE FROM Table_name
WHERE Date_column < DATEADD(mi,-10,GETDATE())
```

Comment: I'm just curious: where does this column `time_created` come from?

Comment: He erroneously assumed that OP has that in his table

Comment: @Trinimon:- I assumed that OP must be having a column to store the timestamp.

Comment: @Rahul: quite optimistic assumption - would he really ask for this, if he had/has one? ;) using ORACLE he could have used flashback tables - more or less successfully ...

Comment: Actually yes , I have this column , and this is the first and probably the last time i need to touch SQL :) , that's why I am asking

Comment: @Trinimon:- Looks like my assumption was really optimistic after watching OP's comment :)

Comment: @StringBuilder, Rahul: ok, I see - that was really a very basic question :) don't mind ;)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has no way to tell at what time the row was created. You will need to have an extra column in your table to log the time. If you do that, your delete statement becomes fairly straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Add a row to your table which holds the created date `modified`.

Create a trigger which updates this row

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trigger_table_update

    ON dbo.MyTable AFTER UPDATE
    AS BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.MyTable  SET modified = GETDATE()
             FROM INSERTED i
                  WHERE dbo.MyTable.ID = i.ID
    END
```

Now you can delete

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE modified  < DATEADD(mm,-10,GETDATE())
```

Please review [How to track when a row was created/updated automatically in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340167/how-to-track-when-a-row-was-created-updated-automatically-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

I use this syntax because I find it easy to use:

This does require that there is an column for timestamps - which should be SOP for any production system.

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, order.credat, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) < 10
```